# sed backreferences and command interpolation

Tags: bash, sed

I am having an interesting issue using *only sed* to substitute short month strings (ex "Oct") with the corresponding number value (ex "10) given a string such as the following:

```
Oct 14 09:23:35 some other input
```

To be replaced directly via `sed` with:

```
14-10-2013 09:23:25 some other input
```

None of the following is actually relevant to solving the trivial problem of month string -> number conversion; I'm more interested in understanding some weird behavior I encountered while trying to solve this problem entirely with sed.

Without any attempt of this string substitution (the `echo` statement is in lieu of the actual input in my script):

```
    ...
    MMM_DD_HH_mm_SS="([A-Za-z]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) (.+:[0-9]{2})"
    echo "Oct 14 09:23:35 some other input" | sed -r "s/$MMM_DD_HH_mm_ss (.+)/\2-\1-\3 \4/"
```

Then how to transform the backreference `\1` into a number. Of course one thinks of using command interpolation with the backreference as an argument:

```
...
TestFunc()
{
    echo "received input $1$1"
}
...
echo "Oct 14 09:23:35 some other input" | sed -r "s/$MMM_DD_HH_mm_ss (.+)/\2-$(TestFunc \\1)-\3 \4/"
```

Where `TestFunc` would be a variation of the `date` command (as proposed by Jotne below) with the `echo`'d date-time group as an input.  Here TestFunc is just an `echo` because I'm much more interested in the behavior of what the function believes to be the value of `$1`.

In this case the `sed` with `TestFunc` produces the output:

```
14-received input OctOct-09:23:35 some other input
```

Which suggests that sed actually *is* inserting backreference `\1` into the command substitution `$(...)` for handling by `TestFunc` (which appears to receive `\1` as the local variable `$1`).

However, all attempts to do anything more with the local `$1` fail.  For example:

```
TestFunc()
{
    echo "processed: $1$1" > tmp.txt # Echo 1

    if [ "$1" == "Oct" ]; then
       echo "processed: 10"
    else
       echo "processed: $1$1"        # Echo 2
    fi
}
```

Returns:

```
14-processed: OctOct-09:23:35 some other input
```

`$1` has been substituted into Echo 2, yet `tmp.txt` contains the value `processed: \1\1`; as if the backreference is not being inserted into the command substitution. Even weirder, the `if` condition fails with `$1` != "Oct", yet it falls through to an `echo` statement which indicates `$1` = "Oct".

My question is why is the backreference insertion working in the case of Echo 2 but not Echo 1? I suspect that the backreference insertion isn't working at all (given the failure of the `if` statement in `TestFunc`) but rather something subtle is going on that makes the substitution appear to work correctly in the case of Echo 2; what is that subtlety?

### Solution

On further reflection I believe I understand what is going on:

- `\\1` is passed to the command substitution subroutine / child function as the literal `\1`. This is why equality test within the child function is failing.
- however the `echo` function *is* correctly handling the string `\\1` as `$1`.  So `echo "aa$1aa"` returns the result of the command substitution to `sed` as `aa\1aa`. Other functions such as `rev` also "see" `$1` as `\1`.
- `sed` then interpolates `\1` in `aa\1aa` as `Oct` or whatever the backreference is, to return `aaOctaa` to the user.

Since command substitution within regexes clearly works, it would be really cool if `sed` replaced the value of `\\1` (or `\1`, whatever) with the backreference **before** executing the command substitution `$(...)`; this would significantly increase sed's power...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
s/$/\nJan01...Oct10Nov11Dec12/;s/(...) (..) (..:..:.. .*)\n.*\1(..).*/\2-\4-2013 \3/;s/\n.*//' file
```

Add a lookup to the end of the line and use the back reference to match on it making sure to remove the lookup table in all cases.

Here's an example of passing a backreference to a function:

```
f(){ echo "x$1y$1z"; }
echo a b c | sed -r  's/(.) (.) (.)/'"$(f \\2)"'/'
```

returns:

```
xbybz
```

HTH

Comment: thank you very much.  both your suggest and Jotne's are helpful, I do wish I understood why `...$(TestFunc \\1)...` almost - but not quite - passes the value of the backreference to `TestFunc` but I need to get back to work.

Comment: @bjsdaiyu see edit for an example that passes a backreference to a function within the RHS of a substitution.

Comment: thanks - what's interesting is that not all versions of sed even allow the `$(...)` execution. i'm not sure whether it's sed or bash that is executing `$(...)`.

Comment: @bjsdaiyu in this case `$(...)` is evaluated in the current bash process (follow the quotes). To evalute it in the process within which the sed command is being run you would need to use the `e` flag and export the function beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct tool:

```
date -d "Oct 14 09:23:35" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
14-10-2013 09:23:35
```

Date does read your input and convert it to any format you like

Comment: That's not very portable.  On my system, -d sets the system's daylight savings bit.

Comment: If it works for the OP, its fine. No all code need to be portable, but its good to make a note that it may not work on all system.

Comment: @Jotne thanks for the suggestion; I should have clarified (and will edit accordingly) that the actual input to `sed` (being simulated with `echo`) includes text after the date-time group (DTG), so I can't simply save the result of a standalone `date` command; this is why I was exploring the `date` command into the sed statement with one of the matched fields as an input.

Comment: You can do like this if you need echo: `d=$(echo "Oct 14 09:23:35")` `date -d "$d" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"`