# Is it possible to pass a backreference to a function from inside sed?

Tags: function, sed, escaping, backreference

**TL;DR**
It is not possible, as "the backreference inside command substitution is not and will not be parsed by sed, but by shell, before running sed" (see answer below).

I want to substitute unicode values for International Phonetic Alphabet with the corresponding characters inside a big text file (>50MB).

My test.txt input example:

```
<CHARSET c="T">02C8;</CHARSET>ku:p<CHARSET c="T">0252;</CHARSET>n] noun<BR>
```

Expected result:

```
<CHARSET c="T">ˈ</CHARSET>ku:p<CHARSET c="T">ɒ</CHARSET>n] noun<BR>
```

I am able to convert a given unicode with this command (e.g.):

```
echo -e "\u02C8"
```

But I'm failing with the escaping inside my sed command. I got the idea to create a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19368887/6375582), like this:

```
codeToChar() { $( echo -e "\u$1"); }
sed -r -i 's#(<CHARSET c="T">)(....)#\1'"$(codeToChar \\2)"'#g' test.txt
```

But it seems the "\2" backreference is not passed to the function:

```
codeToChar() { $( echo -e "\u$1"); }
sed -r -i 's#(<CHARSET c="T">)(....)#\1'"$(codeToChar \\2)"'#g' test.txt
++ codeToChar '\2'
+++ echo -e '\u\2'
++ '\u\2'
./replace.sh: line 2: \u\2: command not found
+ sed -r -i 's#(<CHARSET c="T">)(....)#\1#g' test.tx
```

Comment: I suggest pick other tool. Like python, perl. `sed` is for simple stream editors, it's not like you can dynamically execute external code depending on the line. Sorry, even the first line `codeToChar() { $( echo -e "\u$1"); }` is just invalid - why would you want to execute the result of `echo` execution? I believe re-reading a good introduction to shell would help in better understanding how shell works.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I want to convert the Unicode value using echo. This was suggested here: https://code-examples.net/en/q/93320. I thought using a function would make escaping easier.

Comment: Yes, for __one__ unicode value. Not for some pattern extracted from a file that matches something then replaced with that value written back to the file. That is a task for a programming language, not for sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to properly escape a backreference in sed to pass it to a function?

The presented code properly handles the backreference. The backreference inside command substitution is not and will not be parsed by `sed`, but by shell, before running `sed`. The arguments to a program have to be expanded before running the program.

You may potentially use a GNU extension to `sed` - the `e` flag to `s` command that executes the replacement pattern via `/bin/sh` interpret. Using this flag is highly discouraged and is very hard to use, as figuring the correct quoting and escaping is very hard - it "works" in very simple cases. Because the input string has `;` `<` `>` and also `"` special shell characters I doubt it's possible.

I suggest to pick a full fledged programming language, like python, perl or others, to solve your task. `sed` is not an utility for dynamically executing actions depending on contents of the file, it's a simple stream replacement utility.

In `sed`, it is possible to build a static list of strings to replace, like so:

```
sed -r '
     s/(<CHARSET c="T">)02C8/\1'"$(echo -e "\u02C8")"/
     s/(<CHARSET c="T">)0252/\1'"$(echo -e "\u0252")"/
     .... one s/// command for each character to replace ...
'
```

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer. "The backreference inside command substitution is not and will not be parsed by sed": would you mind explaining why the (linked) example function is working ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365068/sed-backreferences-and-command-interpolation/19368887#19368887

Comment: is that which example?

Comment: Add `set -x` and see for yourself. It generates a sed script like: `sed -r 's/(.) (.) (.)/x\2y\2z/'` and then runs it. It does __not__ substitutes the `\2` for the backreference and then run the bash function, it does it the other way round - runs the function which outputs `x\2y\2z` and then runs `sed`.